# How to show files in django templates from database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to display files in django templates. It's showing successfully from the database. I don't why it's not showing from templates.
Here I am sharing my codes so far.

```
#project urls.py

# for DEBUG=False
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^assets/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),  # for DEBUG=False
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
        {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),  # for DEBUG=False
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and here is the code for others

```
#models.py
class Answer(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Question, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_id.description


class AnswerFile(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(
        Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='files', null=True, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(
        'files', upload_to=path_and_rename, max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.answer)
```

As I need multiple files so I have created another file model with foreign key

```
#forms.py
class AnswerForm(ModelForm):
    # question_id = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ['description']
        widgets = {
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={"class": "form-control", "id": "exampleFormControlTextarea1", "rows": 5, "placeholder": "Add a reply"}),
        }


class AnswerFileForm(AnswerForm):  # extending Answerform
    file = forms.FileField(
        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}), required=False)

    class Meta(AnswerForm.Meta):
        fields = AnswerForm.Meta.fields + ['file', ]

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(AnswerFileForm, self).clean()
        file = cleaned_data.get("file")
        description = cleaned_data.get("description")
        if not file and not description:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This is a required field.")
        return cleaned_data
```

in forms I also try to stay clear and everything is working perfectly in views.py

```
#views.py
    def question_details(request, pk):
        question = Question.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
    
        # answers list
        answers = Answer.objects.filter(question_id=pk).order_by('-id')
        # end answers list
    
        answerForm = AnswerFileForm()
        # start of the answer submission
        if request.method == "POST":
            answerForm = AnswerFileForm(
                request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
            files = request.FILES.getlist('file')
            if answerForm.is_valid():
                question = Question.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
                if question:
                    answer = answerForm.save(commit=False)
                    answer.created_by = request.user
                    answer.question_id = question
                    answer.save()
                    if files:  # check if user has uploaded some files
                        for file in files:
                            AnswerFile.objects.create(answer=answer, file=file)
                    
                    return redirect("fsingle_question", question.pk)
    
        context = {
            "page_title": "Question Details",
            "question": question,
            "answerForm": answerForm,
            "answers": answers
        }
        return render(request, 'ask_question/question_details.html', context)
```

here is the template so far

```
{% for answer in answers %}
        <div class="ms-5">
          <div class="">{{ answer.description }}</div>
          <img src="{{ answer.files }}" width="120" />
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

[image]
in the image you can see the description field is showing perfectly but for files I tried several ways.

though from database it's working perfectly
[image]
[image]

If anyone can help me that will be really appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You write `answer` in your template, but are you not including the iteration over `answers`?

Comment: I used a for loop {% for answer in answers %}

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

We should of course be able to use the accessors for the “other” side of the relationship (in this case, Answer -> AnswerFile) – the link from the related model to the model that defines the relationship.

Since you specify the `related_name = "files"` in `AnswerFile`, you should use that name in stead of the `answerfile_set` when reverse-lookup from `answer`-instances to related files.

```py
answers = Answer.objects.filter(question_id=question_id)
question = answers.first().question_id
```

In your template, you need to iterate over your `answerfiles`:

```
{% for answer in answers %}
        <div class="ms-5">
          <div class="">{{ answer.description }}</div>
          {% for answerfile in answer.files.all %}
              <img src="{{ answerfile }}" width="120" />
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Original answer:

You'll want to study the QuerySet API here [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), and find out what suits you better of `select_related` or `prefetch_related` which both follows foreign key relationships in different ways.

Using `select_related`:

```
AnswerFile.objects.all().select_related("answer__question_id").filter(answer__question_id__id = pk)
```

Comment: do I have to create another context rather than answers?

Comment: I have edited my answer, hopefully that may help you

Comment: it's also not working bro :(